# Is there software out that removes static porn ads from sites?

Tags: ad-blocker, advertising

I want to get rid of flashing GIFS,png,jpg whatever file format.

Answer (score 2):

[uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) is a customizable browser extension that can block almost any content, including porn ads.

Since, by default, uBlock Origin blocks most ads, it should also block any ads promoting pornography.

uBlock Origin is free of cost (gratis) and is open-source.

It works best in the [Firefox web browser from Mozilla](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox), due to functionality available in Firefox, but not in other browsers like Google's Chrome.

Note also that I haven't seen an ad for porn in years, so only visiting sites that are less likely to accept pornography advertisements will also be helpful.

Comment: «Note also that I haven't seen an ad for porn in years, so only visiting sites that are less likely to accept pornography advertisements will also be helpful.» I can't tell the same but you made me laugh :)

Comment: @AFract Whether intentionally or not, I'm happy to make anyone smile. :)  I think you are saying you see porn ads on popular "mainstream" sites.  If my understanding of what you are conveying is correct, do you have a few examples of sites?  The more "mainstream" the better... sites like Google, YouTube, Amazon, Reddit, Yahoo, Bing, StackExchange, ESPN, MSN, Wired, and Lifehacker would be great examples if they fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Googling I've found these:

- Qustodio.com
- Kaspersky Safe Kids
- Net Nanny
- MMGuardian
- Norton Family Premier

I've heard good opinions from Qustodio, but I don't know of any.